# JavaScriptCore Memory Profiling

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, instruments, heap-memory, javascriptcore

I work on a framework that creates multiple JSContexts. I have confirmed they are being deallocated by overriding the ‘dealloc’ method in the class that maintains a reference to them. I’ve also profiled my application using the Allocations tool in Instruments and confirmed there is no recurrent, stacking of memory throughout the application's lifecycle. The memory usage of these JSContexts is currently a point of contention, however.

I’m basically looking to confirm a few things:

1. Are there separate heaps for the native layer and the JS layer?
2. If there are, does the Instruments tool take both into account when looking at ‘All Heap & Anonymous VM’?
3. If not, is there a way to profile the JS heap using Instruments?
4. If not, what would be the best way to profile the JS heap using a real device?

Thank you in advance for any insight.